# Uniqueness of $S(3,4,10)$ Steiner system

Tags: combinatorial-designs, finite-geometry

I don't understand one step in the proof of Theorem 6.3B in the book "Permutation Groups" by J.D.Dixon-M.Mortimer.

Let 00, 01, ..., 22 be the points of affine geometry $AG_2(3)$. Then there are exactly nine quadrangles containing points 00 and 01; they contain these additional points: 
$Q_1: 10,11$; $Q_2: 10,12$; $Q_3: 10,21$; 
$Q_4: 11,12$; $Q_5: 11,20$; $Q_6: 12,22$;
$Q_7: 20,21$; $Q_8: 20,22$; $Q_9: 21,22$.
Denote the set of these nine quadrangles $\cal Q(00,01)$.

Let $\cal S$ be a set of 18 quadrangles of $AG_2(3)$ such that each triangle of $AG_2(3)$ is in a unique quadrangle from $\cal S$.
Since there are six triangles which contain the points 00 and 01 and each quadrangle contains four triangles it follows that $\cal S$ must contain exactly three of the quadrangles $Q_1$ - $Q_9$. It is now said that it leaves only three possibilities for $\cal S\cap \cal Q(00,01)$: $\{Q_1,Q_6,Q_7\}$, $\{Q_2,Q_5,Q_9\}$ or $\{Q_3,Q_4,Q_8\}$. I don't understand why there is not a possibility $\{Q_3, Q_5, Q_6\}$.

Comment: I could fill in some of the missing context, but the library is three flights down, so... The part I have trouble filling in is about the design being on a set of size ten, but there are only nine points in your geometry! I don't know what exactly is required from the quadrangles for the design to work, but I suspect that the following observation may be related: Consider the third point $P_i$ on the line determined by the two non-fixed points of $Q_i$. IOW $P_1=12$, $P_2=11$, $P_3=02$, $P_4=10$, $P_5=02$, $P_6=02$, $P_7=22$, $P_8=21$, $P_9=20$.

Comment: Observe that your suggested set of quadrangles $\{Q_3,Q_5,Q_6\}$ shares the same extra point, namely $P_3=P_5=P_6=02$. I don't know if this is significant for the construction of the design, but it just might be?

Comment: Yes, the design starts with $S(2,3,9)$ (aka $AG_2(3)$) and extends it to $S(3,4,10)$ by adding one new point (say $P$). The new blocks of length 4 are of two types: 12 blocks are of type $\{X_1,X_2,X_3,P\}$ for every block $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ of $AG_2(3)$ and the set $\cal S$ of 18 blocks consists of quadrangles from $AG_2(3)$ - they must fulfill the condition each triangle of AG2(3) is in a unique quadrangle from $\cal S$.

Comment: By the way, the exactly same construction is described [here](http://seis.bristol.ac.uk/~sh15083/documents/04.15_MT5999.pdf) in section 4.2, Theorem 4.10. I need to think over your observation but I think that it is connected with the fact that quadrangles from the set $\{Q_3,Q_5,Q_6\}$ are from different sets $\cal S_1$, $\cal S_2$, $\cal S_3$ which partition the set of all quadrangles (definition 4.6 in the linked document). And this is exactly the reason why I have problem with the uniqueness part of the proof: otherwise the fourth possibility would be isomorphic with previous three.